# Where's the PATH variable stored if .zshrc doesn't exist?

Tags: path, environment-variables, zsh, zshrc

I'm using zsh as default. I'm also uncomfortable with environment variables and trying to learn about it.

Recently i've added a path to my PATH variable but noticed that .zshrc doesn't exist in my home(~/) directory. I can echo my path variable and the path has been added so:

Where is the PATH variable stored if .zshrc doesn't exist?

OS: Big Sur

Comment: In **macOS Big Sur** (and other version of **macOS**) the default _system file_ that provides the default `path` is `/private/etc/paths`. There is also the `/private/etc/paths.d` _directory_ which some _applications/utilities_ will write to so its _path_ is added to the `path` (`PATH`). In my `$HOME` _directory_ I have a `.zprofile` _file_ in which I've added to the default `path`.

Comment: Note that `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d/` are not used implicitly. `/etc/profile` is (likely) sourced first, and evaluates the output of `/usr/libexec/path_helper`, which reads from those files to produce its output.

Comment: @papekoja: Environment variables are not stored in **files**, they are stored in the **environment** of a process, as the name implies, and they are inherited to child processes. If nobody ever sets a variable in the environment, the variable does not exist. `PATH` is not an exception. Zsh sources during startup several files, which may or may not contain code to set the environment. Note also that even putting such a code into .zshrc, does not mean that every zsh will contain the definition, because .zshrc is only sourced by an **interactive** zsh.

Answer (score 0):

The shell will normally inherit `PATH` from its parent process. If no `PATH` env var exists many shells will call `sysctl(USER_CS_PATH,...)` to ask the OS tell what search path to use by default. There are also other initialization files that a shell like zsh will read. From the output of `man zsh`:

```
FILES
   $ZDOTDIR/.zshenv
   $ZDOTDIR/.zprofile
   $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc
   $ZDOTDIR/.zlogin
   $ZDOTDIR/.zlogout
   ${TMPPREFIX}*   (default is /tmp/zsh*)
   /etc/zshenv
   /etc/zprofile
   /etc/zshrc
   /etc/zlogin
   /etc/zlogout    (installation-specific - /etc is the default)
```